# Issue with Hybrid Azure AD join of Windows 7 devices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to do Hybrid Azure Ad join of Windows 7 devices but while trying to enable Hybrid Azure Ad join in AD connect the check box for Supported Windows Downlevel domain-joined devices is disabled.Hybrid Azure AD join of Windows 10 devices are working fine.

Any suggestions why it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases if you can not enable an option it means it is not support.